# Android : TabListener is stop working

Tags: android

I'am trying to do Tab View application. I'am using getFragmentManager() method to get other fragments. But it stops working when i run the application. If i give getSupportFragmentManager() then it asks to change type of simpleListFragment to Fragment. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Here is the Activity code.

```
public class TapBar extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabview);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_section1).setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_section2).setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_section3).setTabListener(this));
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;  
}
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction)             {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

 /**
  * On first tab we will show our list
  */
 if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
  MyFriendsListFragment simpleListFragment = new MyFriendsListFragment();
  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, simpleListFragment).commit();
 } 
 else if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
  AndroidList androidlidt = new AndroidList();
  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, androidlidt).commit();
 }      
 else {

  AndroidVersionList androidversionlist = new AndroidVersionList();
  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, androidversionlist).commit();
 }
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
in your MyFriendsListFragment ,AndroidList ,AndroidVersionList 
insted  import android.app.ListFragment;